# Даниил или Данила?

Tags: общие-вопросы

В укр. свидетельстве о рождении написано Данило, в рос. паспорте в графе "Дети" написано Данила, а назвали мы ребенка Даниил.

Нужно ли исправлять в паспорте Данила на Даниил? Даниил и Данила - это разные имена или это одно и тоже?

Answer (score 2):

С юридической точки зрения, это всё разные имена. Одному моему знакомому, ГенадИевичу, пришлось на уровне главы города получать справку, подтверждающую что в документах на квартиру ГенадЬевич из документов и он, это одно и то же лицо. Документы, конечно, лучше унифицировать во избежание, а вот как, зависит от гражданства ребёнка. Насколько знаю, по украинским законам некоторые русские имена в принудительном порядке украинизируются, поэтому в этом случае проще записать его в российском паспорте как *Данило* (хотя можно и *Данила* оставить, т. к. перевод с украинского, а вот с Даниил могут быть и проблемы с особо ретивыми чиновниками). Если ребёнку тоже будете получать гражданство РФ, то тогда и унифицируйте данные в документах.